# How to fetch part of URL for use as variable in Template.events

Tags: javascript, meteor

I think i have a basics question, but i cant figure it out.

My Meteor app shows a list of mongodb values for a specific collection. These items can be clicked and the details of this record will be shown. The mongodb _id is used in the url to show the specific data.

On the second page, the detailed page, this item is show, and some buttons with values. I like to achieve that when one of these buttons is pressed, the item will be updated with the value of that specific button.

So basically what i like to do is get the part of the url where the mongodb _id is, and use it as variable in my Template.events. So i know i update the correct item.

The url looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/userstory/3XBe6vEQJrZ46B6ik
```

My questions is, what syntax do i need to use to get the _id (last part of the URL) as input?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's a really hacky way to get the id. A better approach is to set it in a session variable in your router. e.g. `Session.set('currentStoryId', this.params.storyId)`.

Comment: That sounds very logical, setting it is no problem, but can i get it back with session.get in different .js file? Thats the whole point right? :) Well i am going to try it. Thanks

Comment: I am doing something wrong, setting it seems to be fine. By am  not able to read it back in another .js file :( Well i keep trying. But any more suggestion are welcome :)

Comment: The session is global, so you should be able to access it from another file.

Comment: Then i am doing something wrong. This is how i set it:Session.set('currentStoryId', this.params._id)  and how i retrieve it: var usId = Session.get('currentStoryId')

Comment: Do a `console.log(this.params._id)` right before you set it. And see if that prints anything.

Comment: Also, make sure you run the Session.get after you actually set it. Can you show us the function when you are using it? Is it in .rendered ? or template helpers? Or just right in the top level of .js file?